# How to sum all rows for each column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df as such:

```
         column A    column B    column C  .... ColumnZ 
 index
   X        1           4           7              10
   Y        2           5           8              11
   Z        3           6           9              12
```

For the life on me I can't figure out how to sum rows for each column, to arrive at a summation df:

```
         column A    column B    column C  .... ColumnZ 
 index
 total       6           16          25             33
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `df.sum().to_frame().T.rename_axis('Total')` ... ?

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

```
df.loc['total'] = df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=0)
```

Comment: I would just like to add: df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1) to sum the columns instead of rows. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column A': [1, 2, 3], 'column B': [4, 5, 6], 'column C': [7, 8, 9]})

df.loc['total'] = df.sum()

print(df)
```

Output:

```
       column A  column B  column C
0             1         4         7
1             2         5         8
2             3         6         9
total         6        15        24
```